# Расчет расстояния, времени и скорости используя Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

Подскажите как сделать. У меня 2 кнопки "Старт" и "Стоп", карта google maps api v2. Хотелось бы сделать так, при нажатии кнопки старт будет определить начальную точку, а при Стоп это конец. И считать между ними расстояние, скорость. Мне нужно не прямую линию между точками, а по карте, например человек бежит по кругу, 2 круга по 3 км, получается 6 км. Как это сделать, подскажите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут даже карта не нужна. Подписываешься на событие получения координат, и считаешь расстояние между пришедшими точками, вот тут более подробно как получить координаты.

[Ответ на Stack Overflow на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591147/how-to-get-current-location-in-android).

А вот так можно узнать расстояние между двумя точками:

```
public static double CalculationDistance(LatLng StartP, LatLng EndP) {
        return CalculationDistanceByCoord(StartP.latitude, StartP.longitude, EndP.latitude, EndP.longitude);
}

private static double CalculationDistanceByCoord(double startPointLat,double startPointLon,double endPointLat,double endPointLon){
        float[] results = new float[1];
        Location.distanceBetween(startPointLat, startPointLon, endPointLat, endPointLon, results);
        return results[0];
}
```

Comment: но подскажите как взять начало и конец ?
я пытался делать но приложение вылетает force closed принажатии на кнопки старт